# How can I put a BackgroundImage in Xamarin.Forms UWP?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml

Good Day everyone. I'm currently creating the UWP part of my Xamarin.Forms Project and I want to put a BackgroundImage in it. I've noticed that the images I used in Xamarin.Forms.Droid are not being displayed on my UWP. Why is that so?

I used this code **BackgroundImage="filename.jpg"**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check the image and make sure that you place your images in the **application's root directory** with `Build Action: Content`.

---

### **Edit :**

I suggest you to modify the code as :

```
BackgroundImage="//Assets/filename.jpg"
```

Comment: Sir where can i found the  **application's root directory**? I've added the image to the Assets folder of my UWP.

Comment: Place the image inside uwp project. Right click UWP project -> Add existing item -> add your image

Comment: I'm having the same problem, my background image displays on Android but not on UWP. I'm using backgroundImage="background1" in MainPage.xaml. I put the image in Resources for Android and bigger image in Assets folder for UWP. I also set build action to content and copy to output directory = copy if newer